# AngularJS timeout http

Tags: angularjs

I got a perfectly working service

```
this.getcustomers= function() { 
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        $http({
                            method: 'GET',
                            url: 'api/customers'
                        }).then(function success(data) {
                            deferred.resolve(data.data);
                          }, function error(error) {
                            deferred.reject(error);
                          });
                        return deferred.promise;
                    };
```

How do i add a `timeout` to the above. I tried samples from stackoverflow but nothing is working
I need the request to keep trying for 5000 ms and show an error when that time passes.
Adding `timeout : timeout|promise` does not work with me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this one helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015416/how-to-set-a-global-http-timeout-in-angularjs

Comment: Yeah i tried this one sadly not solving my issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a `retry` mechanism, rather than a `timeout`. Timeout means "perform an action after X time", in JS anyway.

See the answer here, should be what you're looking for:
[AngularJS service retry when promise is rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595886/angularjs-service-retry-when-promise-is-rejected)

Comment: That actually worked, but how can i keep on trying for `X` number of seconds?

Comment: Well, instead of checking number of retries, compare times. Save a timestamp of the first attempt. You can use `Date.now()` to get a unix timestamp. Then keep retrying until `Date.now() - startTime` is greater than whatever you want to limit it to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working link of [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjqLthtk/)

```
function httpRequestHandler () {
            var timeout = $q.defer(),
                result = $q.defer(),
                timedOut = false,
                httpRequest;

            $timeout(function () {
                timedOut = true;
                timeout.resolve();
            }, (1000 * $scope.timeout));

            httpRequest = $http({
                method : 'post',
                url: '/echo/json/',
                data: createData(),
                cache: false,
                timeout: timeout.promise
            });

            httpRequest.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                result.resolve(data);
            });

            httpRequest.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if (timedOut) {
                    result.reject({
                        error: 'timeout',
                        message: 'Request took longer than ' + $scope.timeout + ' seconds.'
                });
                } else {
                    result.reject(data);
                }
            });

            return result.promise;
        }
```

Comment: That was the first one i found, i changed it to `.then` instead of `.success` and `.error` and tried implementing it but did not work

Comment: It is recommended as on the `$http` on AngularJS docs. Or am i missing something?

Comment: yes you can use simple .success and .error callbacks, if your requirement fullfilled.